# Can type constructor be the same as value constructor?

Tags: haskell, types

In the [Haskell tutorial,](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses) I see an expression like this

```
data Vector a = Vector a a a deriving (Show)
```

Probably not the same, but very similar. I'm a bit confused. Could anyone explain what it is doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data Vector a = MkVector a a a
```

defines a parameterized data type, `Vector a` for any type `a`.

It also defines a way for us to create values of that type: by using a data constructor function `MkVector` with three parameters of the same type.

For whatever type `a`, calling `MkVector` with three values of type `a` produces a value of type `Vector a`. For example,

```
let a :: Int ; a = 1 ; v = MkVector a 3 4 in v :: Vector Int

let a :: Float ; a = 1 ; v = MkVector a 3 4 in v :: Vector Float
```

It so happens that we are allowed to use the same name as in the type, `Vector`, as the name of the data constructor as well. This can be confusing at first.

Answer (score 1):

This defines a new datatype called `Vector`. Let's break it up into a few different parts:

```
data Vector a     -- Type part
  = Vector a a a  -- Constructor part
  deriving (Show) -- Automatic derivation part
```

The type part says that "The following will be defined to have type `Vector a`, where `a` is some not yet known type":

```
data Vector a     -- Type part
```

The constructor part defines a function `Vector :: a -> a -> a -> Vector a`. Note that types and values have different namespaces and thus can have the same name.

```
  = Vector a a a  -- Constructor part
```

The automatic derivation part tells the compiler to automatically implement the function `show` for this type, allowing us to ignore the details. If you don't yet know about typeclasses, don't worry too much about what this means, but bear in mind that without this you can't `show` or `print` these values.

```
  deriving (Show) -- Automatic derivation part
```

We can play with these values in GHCi:

```
λ> data Vector a = Vector a a a deriving (Show)
λ> Vector 1 2 3
Vector 1 2 3
λ> :type Vector True False True
Vector True False True :: Vector Bool
λ> :type Vector "Hello," " World" "!"
Vector "Hello," " World" "!" :: Vector [Char]
```

Comment: I understand this. But in English or in Math, I still don't know in what condition we could get a `Vector a` from the input `Vector a a a`. And also, should we avoid using the same type constructor name and value constructor name?

Comment: @user8314628 I don't understand what you mean by "in what condition ...", but it is not bad practice to use the same value and constructor names, as long as you're not using the `DataKinds` language extension.

Comment: A `Vector 1 2 3` value can have type `Vector Int`.  If you use the `Vector` constructor fully applied (three fields) then you will always end up with a value of type `Vector a` for some `a`.

Comment: I’m mostly happy with this answer but I don’t really like the phrase “where `a` is some not yet known type.” It seems it could be read as implying that once you’ve made a `Vector Int` you can no longer make a `Vector String`. On the other hand I can’t think of a good concise way to write it

Comment: @DanRobertson brevity can be enemy of clarity. matters of elegance to the tailor and to the cobbler, etc.

Comment: @WillNess you seem to have come up with a good way to put it in your own answer

Comment: @DanRobertson I just like that quote, and try to bring it up when appropriate. :)

Comment: @AJFarmar Now I understand it better. Could I regard `a` in `Vector a` as some kind of container that has a `Vector a a a` in it, where `Vector a` and `Vector a a a` are 2 totally different things?

Comment: @user8314628 The `a` in `Vector a` is a type variable, the type-level equivalent of the `x` in `\x -> x + 1`. It allows you to make a vector of any type.